Does a Jew have to be the one doing libun hagalah
According to Halacha, does a Jew have to be the person who does hagalah or Libun, or can a gentile do it with proper instruction?

Miss your questions Kirk! Hope you are alright :)

I asked your question to R Binyamin Tabady who rules it is permitted if the non-Jew is properly instructed and supervised. He brought as a proof the Shulchan Aruch in Hilchot Melicha (salting) YD 69:10 with the Pitchei Tshuva 69:17. He mentioned libun, like melicha, is a d'rabbanan. (personal comment: the Rema mentions one of the two conditions of instructed/supervised is enough).

Libbun is not derabanan in all cases

R Tabady mentioned there is no mitsva of libun, like there is no mitsva of melicha (unlike shechita) - what you want is the result. But maybe there are counter examples?

I didn't say there is a mitzva of libbun. I agree there's no "lishmah" type issue here. I'm not sure why you are discussing if something is deorayta or derabanan?

Because the halacha quoted is on melicha, a d'rabannan, so you have to say libun is also d'rabannan to learn from melicha

Don't you agree libbun on a ben yomo pork-grill is deorayta? Derabanan isn't enough to learn from melicha, since as you said we want a result here. The main thing you have to establish if you want to learn from melicha is that we want a result in both. But honestly, the fact that we trust a non-jew to achieve a result with supervision is pretty trivial and for this answer I don't really think you need to bother proving from melicha.
